# How insert ST_POINT in HANA from Node.js?

Tags: node.js, hana

I'm having some issues trying to insert coordinates inside `ST_POINT`, here is my code:

I'm using the official library for HANA [SAP/node-hdb](https://github.com/SAP/node-hdb)

first attempt:

```
statement.exec([
  [
  ....
  `new ST_POINT ('POINT (${latitud} ${longitud})')`
  ]
], (err, rows) => {
```

> TypeError: value.copy is not a function, start using Buffer

second attempt:

```
statement.exec([
  [
  ....
  Buffer.from(`new ST_POINT ('POINT (${latitud} ${longitud})')`)
  ]
], (err, rows) => {
```

> Error: internal error: exception  1: no.1600401  (spatial/parser/WkbParser.cpp:54) Invalid WKB byte order (110) at position 0

Any advice? Thanks

Comment: can you provide the complete resulting insert statement? The syntax for the ST_POINT() constructor looks OK so far, but the resulting SQL is probably crooked.

Answer (score 1):

It looks like it might just be that you might have the values reversed. It should actually be longitude, latitude and not latitude, longitude that it looks like you have in your code example.

```
new ST_POINT ('POINT (${longitud} ${latitud})')
```

Similar example using the hdb library would be

```
client.exec('select ST_GeomFromText( \'Point( 129.4199982 35.98789978 )\' from dummy', function (err, rows) {
  if (err) {
    return console.error('Error:', err);
  }
  console.log(rows);
});
```

I am guessing at the SQL since you did not show the full SQL in your example.

For the full GIS info on you can find more here, https://help.sap.com/viewer/cbbbfc20871e4559abfd45a78ad58c02/2.0.02/en-US/7a2d5618787c10148dc4da810379e15b.html

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow, please review: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer